# Any updated sha1sum for MS-Windows available anywhere?

Tags: windows, mac, security

The only sha1sum (seems no sha256sum) for MS-Windows was done by one of the GNUPG people way back in 2004. See https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-announce/2004q4/000184.html

and the binary can be seen browsed/looked at ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/binary/

With github and such public-facing repositories has somebody superseded that release.

I am looking for a tool which is able to check hashes of any .iso image or just plain applications, provided hashes have been provided by the .iso provider to check them against.

In Unix I can simply do :-

```
$sha1sum -c sha1sum
```

And provided I have hash checksum and a binary and the binary is there in the drive, it will check and if it's the same, will say

```
$sha1sum -c sha1sum 
Application :OK
ISO-Image.iso: OK
```

I hope people now got the idea.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?  When you indicate "MS-Windows" what are you referencing exactly?

Comment: MS-Windows = Microsoft Windows, any version, from XP to 7 to 10.

Comment: So you want the checksum of any version of Windows.  The checksum of every component or just the .ISO files which Microsoft already provides.  If you want an answer please clarify your question.  Your question in its current form is not clear and unanswerable.  Be specific please.

Comment: If you follow the first link, I think the poster's looking for a tool that runs on Windows to generate SHA1 hashes, not the actual SHA1 hash value of Windows itself. SHA1 hasn't changed, so if the old binary still works, it will still generate correct hashes. If it doesn't, maybe you can find a newer openssl release for Windows, openssl can generate hashes (including SHA1).

Comment: @blm - I went to the first link before I submitted my first comment.  What the author wants is still not clear.  It should not be hard to clarify what they are looking for.  As you point out the application still works.

Comment: @Ramhound Actually I didn't say the binary still works, I said *if* it works, then it should be usable as SHA1 hasn't changed. It wouldn't surprise me if a binary compiled in 2004 doesn't run on recent Windows releases. I agree completely though, the original poster should clarify what they're asking for.

Comment: I have just tried the [sha1sum.exe binary](ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/binary/sha1sum.exe) on my Win7 64-bit machine. It runs fine. Recompilation should not be too difficult. The source is available under the first link.

Comment: There is a [sha256sum binary](https://kanguru.zendesk.com/entries/21747773-SHA256-Checksum-Utility) available online with some additional parameters.

Comment: What about Mac, any ideas anybody ?